# My facebook login dialog box does not close in IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, facebook, authentication, dialog

I have a strange problem. After I enter my Facebook login details in the popup dialogbox it returns a blank page and the popup never closes. This only happens in IE. In Chrome, FF and even Safari it works perfectly.  Can you please help me to fix this issue? I want to know what exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem like you describe.

I solved it by providing a channelUrl with a channel.html file in the FB.init like this:

```
FB.init({ appId: '[your appid]', channelUrl: 'http://[your website]/channel.html', status: true, cookie: true,
                xfbml: true
            })
```

The channel.html file should only contain the script line to the connect facebook all js file as what now should be on your page close to the FB.Init. After you placed that line of code in the channel.html file, remove it from your page.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

It took a college of mine hours to find out, it had a really weird cause, but he solved the issue:

he replaced:

```
<a href="#" onclick="fbLogin(); return false;">Login</a>
```

by

```
<a href="javascript:fbLogin();">Login</a>
```

the function fbLogin() triggered the popup via FB.login()

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this happens when you are testing your site in a different URL than the one that you have set into your app configuration. Check that your canvas and the rest of URLs are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by implementing the suggestions on this page which include adding a channel url as suggested in mlapre's answer:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/530/

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20121107015111/http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/530/